# Error with developer.android.com basic training EXTRA_MESSAGE can not be resolved

Tags: java, android

(background)
I'm starting to learn to program android devices with Android studio. I don't have any experience with Java or XML, so I started the course @ (https://developer.android.com). Currently, I am learning how I can start a new activity (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). However, the code throws out an error which I don't understand.

(Issue)
using API 18: Android 4.3 (Jelly Bean) and this code:

```
package com.fakecompany.practice1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);           //the error
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

throw's an error at:

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
```

Cannot resolve symbol 'EXTRA_MESSAGE'

it suggest i import

```
android.provider.AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE;
```

But that cannot be right. What did I do wrong?

Comment: From the site you missed    `public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";` In your case you can use your package name  `com.fakecompany.practice1.MESSAGE`

Comment: @Raghunandan Ji : It may be answer :p

Comment: @Raghunandan could you put it in as an answer? because it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's just key pair value. so you can use your own Key value for sending data between activities.
btw, you missed this

```
 public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
```

try adding this. you can send data and receive between activities, service etc.
hope it answers your question.